# How to create rows of tables using loop in PHP

Tags: php, yii, html-table

I have been trying to create rows in a table in Yii using PHP but somehow I am not able to do that. I have attached the code below.

**PHP** code:

```
<div class="grid_16">
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th style="width:33%;" id="wall_userNameStyle"><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($Facility,'cname'); ?></th>
<th style="width:33%;margin:0 0.5%" id="wall_userNameStyle"><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($Facility,'cregistration'); ?></th>
<th style="width:33%" id="wall_userNameStyle"><?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($Facility,'cannual'); ?></th>
</tr>

<?php $j=0;
for($j; $j<5; $j++)
{
?>
<tr>
<td style="width:33%;"><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($Facility,"raymond[$j][0]",array('class' => 'edit_textbox','style' => 'width:99%')) ; ?></td> 

<td style="width:33%;margin:0 0.5%"><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($Facility,"raymond[$j][1]",array('class' => 'edit_textbox','onkeypress'=>'return number_only(event)','style' => 'width:99%')) ; ?></td> 

<td style="width:33%;"><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($Facility,"raymond[$j][2]",array('class' => 'edit_textbox','onkeypress'=>'return number_only(event)','style' => 'width:99%')) ; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `</table>` is in your loop... take it outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is

```
<?php 
for($j = 0; $j<5; $j++)
{
?>
<tr>
<td style="width:33%;"><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($Facility,"raymond[$j][0]",array('class' => 'edit_textbox','style' => 'width:99%')) ; ?></td> 

<td style="width:33%;margin:0 0.5%"><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($Facility,"raymond[$j][1]",array('class' => 'edit_textbox','onkeypress'=>'return number_only(event)','style' => 'width:99%')) ; ?></td> 

<td style="width:33%;"><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($Facility,"raymond[$j][2]",array('class' => 'edit_textbox','onkeypress'=>'return number_only(event)','style' => 'width:99%')) ; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>

</table>
</div>
```

You had the closing `</table>` in side of the loop which was closing your table early

Comment: i appreciate your help. Yeah that's I didn't loop the way I wanted!

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `</table>` outside of your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
<table>
<th>
//information
</th>
<tr>
<?php
$j = 0;
for($j = 0; $j<5; $j++)
{
echo "<td>";
echo //table information 1
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo //table information 2
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo //table information 3
echo "</td>";
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

The table information can be anything or any amount.